# c# Bitlocker information from Active Directory

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory

I'm trying to get bit locker recovery information for all users from active directory via below functions.
I've tried many different solution but none of them solved my problem. 
I can get most of the computer properties like Operation System,Service Pack expect bit locker info.
Is there any special permission or method to search with msFVE-RecoveryInformation ?

Method 1:

```
 DirectoryEntry child = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://XXXXX");
        DirectoryEntries enteries = child.Children;
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(child);
        ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(cn=computerName))";
        ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        SearchResultCollection item = ds.FindAll();

        //string dn = item.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["distinguishedname"].Value.ToString();
        string temp1 = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.DistinguishedName;
        child = new DirectoryEntry(("LDAP://" + temp1), "XXXXX", "XXXXX");
        enteries = child.Children;
        ds = new DirectorySearcher(child);
        ds.Filter = "(objectClass=msFVE-RecoveryInformation)";
        ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        SearchResultCollection result = ds.FindAll();

        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (SearchResult sr in result)
            {
                string recoveryKeyPackage = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["msFVE-KeyPackage"].Value.ToString();
                string recoveryGUID = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["msFVE-RecoveryGuid"].Value.ToString();
                string recoveryPassword = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["msFVE-RecoveryPassword"].Value.ToString();
                string recoveryVolumeGUID = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["msFVE-VolumeGuid"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
           Console.Write ("No recovery information found!");
        }
```

Method 2:

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> GetBitlockerKeys(string computerName)
    {
        DirectoryEntry dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://XXXX");
        var keys = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        using (var computerObject = dEntry)
        {
            var children = computerObject.Children;
            var schemaFilter = children.SchemaFilter;
            schemaFilter.Add("msFVE-RecoveryInformation");
            foreach (DirectoryEntry child in children) using (child)
                {
                    var recoveryGuid = new Guid((byte[])child.Properties["msFVE-RecoveryGuid"].Value).ToString();
                    var recoveryPassword = child.Properties["msFVE-RecoveryPassword"].Value.ToString();
                    if (!keys.ContainsKey(recoveryGuid))
                    {
                        keys.Add(recoveryGuid, recoveryPassword);
                    }
                }
        }

        return keys;
    }
```

Comment: By default I don't think anyone has rights to read those attributes. You'll need to delegate that and I bet you'll be in business.

Comment: @BrianDesmond thanks for your answer. Do you aware any method for this ?

Comment: Delegating permissions? Your AD administrator should have no problem doing this. Here's an article I wrote a few years ago to get you going - http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/delegating-privileges-active-directory.